# Bash "Permission denied" issue when trying to append to EOF

Tags: permissions, cat

When trying to push a couple lines to the end of a file, I get a permission issue. I understand why I'm getting the error, but I can't think of a way to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sudo cat > /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini << EOF
    # extensions
    extension=”memcached.so”
    extension=”apc.so”
EOF
```

Comment: `ls -al /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, what's the permission settings of the file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Heredoc usage, or "appending to EOF", is *not* the problem.

All redirections (including `>`) are **applied *before* executing the actual command.** In other words, your shell first tries to open `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` for writing **using your account**, then runs a completely useless `sudo cat`.

One way to get around this:

```
sudo bash -c "cat >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" <<EOF
```

(You can run an interactive shell via `sudo -s`, or use `dd` or `tee` for writing to the file.)

---

On a related note, using **`>` will *overwrite*** the old php.ini. **Use `>>` to append.**

Comment: Thanks grawity. I'm having issues running the above for hidden files. I get this kind of response: http://cl.ly/3K2J3Q2N1h2I3N364301

Comment: @onassar: If you open the heredoc with "`EOF`", you must close it with exactly the same "`EOF`". *Not* with "`.EOF`" as you are currently doing.

Comment: this is the code I'm pasting in: http://cl.ly/1w3s1p2J3U1I3C1j0q1O it's actually just being rendered improperly by my terminal.

Comment: it seems the tabs in my code (\t character) was throwing things off. replacing those with 4 spaces did the trick. thx!

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the answer by @grawity, showing how to use tee:

```
sudo tee /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini >/dev/null <<EOF
    # extensions
    extension=”memcached.so”
    extension=”apc.so”
EOF
```

or use the "-a" option of tee for appending instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo su` and then you have a proper shell as `root`. Run the command in there, without `sudo` prefix. Afterwards, `exit` to return from the root shell.